# Excluding one more value from MODE function on Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

For the moment I find myself with a problem in my formula. I have a huge list of numbers in my column A, where I want to know the number that occurs most often (using the mode function). To do so, I also had to exclude 0 as a number.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(mode(ifs(A2:A50<>0;A2:A50)))
```

However, I want to know which number occurs most often after the first number. I tried this formula but did not get results, I continued to get the 41 (which is the number that occurs most times in this list).

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(mode(ifs(A2:A50<>0;A2:A50;A2:A50<>B2;A2:A50)))
```

How can I solve it so that I can ask for a 3rd number that occurs more often?
Thank you!

Comment: Hmm sorry. I always tend to call Excel to Google Spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

`=QUERY(index(if({1,1},A:A)),
"select Col1, Count(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 order by Count(Col2) desc")`

- `index(if({1,1},A:A)` is to [double the column](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VY157ykKsCVDqEKDBp3oAVaG0LTXAz8wUCggCrFXMDM/edit#gid=594466526).

EDIT.

`=QUERY({A:A},
"select Col1, Count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 order by Count(Col1) desc")`

Comment: Hi Renato Dimas, you may try entering the formula into some empty cell.